# Is there any method to compute $\frac{d^{n}}{d x^{n}}\left(\cos ^{k} x\right)$ other than complex numbers?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, complex-numbers, binomial-theorem

In this couple of days, I need to know the high derivatives of $cos^kx$ whose power $k$ make the differentiation much harder.  Then I attempt to
use the identity $$
\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{x i}+e^{-x i}\right),
$$

to expand it with Binomial expansion
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos ^{k} x &=\frac{1}{2 ^k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}e^{x(k-j) i} e^{-x i j} 
=\frac{1}{2^{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j} e^{x(k-2 j) i}
\end{aligned}
$$

Differentiating it by $n$ times yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^{n}}{d x^{n}}\left(\cos ^{k} x\right) &=\frac{1}{2^k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}[(k-2 j) i]^{n} e^{x(k-2 j) i} \\
&=\frac{i^{n}}{2 ^k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}(k-2 j)^{n} e^{x(k-2 j) i} \\
&=\frac{i^{n}}{2^{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}(k-2 j)^{n}[\cos ((k-2 j) x)+i \sin ((k-2 j) x)]
\end{aligned}
$$

If $x$ is **real**, then comparing the imaginary and real parts on both sides yields \begin{equation}
\displaystyle \frac{d^{n}}{d x^{n}}\left(\cos ^{k} x\right)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2^{k-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{k}{j}(k-2 j)^{n}\cos((k-2j)x) \quad \textrm{ if n is even.}\\\displaystyle 
\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{2^{k-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{k}{j}(k-2 j)^{n} \sin((k-2j)x)  \quad \textrm{ if n is odd.}
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

---

---

For examples,

1. When $n$ is even,

$$
\left.\frac{d^{n}}{d x^{n}}\left(\cos ^{k} x\right)\right|_{x=0}=\frac{(-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2^{k-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{k}{j}(k-2 j)^{n}
$$

In particular,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left.\frac{d^{6}}{d x^{6}}\left(\cos ^{5} x\right)\right|_{x=0}&=\frac{(-1)^{3}}{2^{4}} \sum_{j=0}^{2}\binom{5}{j}(5-2 j)^{6} \\
&=\frac{1}{16}\left[5^{6}+5 \cdot 3^{6}+10 \cdot 1^{6}\right] \\
&=1205
\end{aligned}
$$

2. When $n$ is odd,$$
   \left.\frac{d^{n}}{d x^{n}}\left(\cos ^{k} x\right)\right|_{x=0}=0;
   $$
   $$\left.\frac{d^{n}}{d x^{n}}\left(\cos ^{k} x\right) \right|_{x=\frac{\pi}{4} }= 
   \frac{(-1)^{\frac{n+1}{2}}}{2^{k-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{k}{j}(k-2 j)^{n} \sin \frac{(k-2 j) \pi}{4} $$

**Can we find its closed form without using the complex numbers?**

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3370249/693161)'s a reference.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, I want it for any $x\in R$, not just at 0.

Comment: It looks odd that you call the cases " $n\equiv 1,3\pmod 4$ and $n\equiv 0,2 \pmod 4$ " instead of "$n$ odd and $n$ even".

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I had changed them.

Answer (score 6):

Although essentially equivalent, you can say

$$\cos^k(x)=\frac1{2^k}\sum_{j=0}^k{k\choose j}\cos(k-2j)x,$$
which can be proved by induction on $k$, together with the sum formula. Now, differentiating is fairly straightforward, based on casework on $n\pmod 4$.

Comment: Thank you for your identity by which we can find the formula faster.

Comment: There is more about this formula in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4300731/how-to-express-the-nth-power-of-the-cosine-as-a-series-of-cosines).

Comment: My bad, it's sloppy notation, I meant $\cos((k-2j)x)$.

Comment: @KentaS I guess we have to write $\cos((k-2j)x)$ and $\sin((k-2j)x)$. Am I right?

Comment: No induction is needed. Just apply the real part to the identity mentioned in the question \begin{aligned}
\cos ^{k} x &=\frac{1}{2 ^k} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j}e^{x(k-j) i} e^{-x i j} 
=\frac{1}{2^{k}} \sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j} e^{x(k-2 j) i}
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), with $g(x)=\cos(x)$ and $f(x)=x^k$.

Just for an example, with $\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\cos^4(x)$ you need to sum over $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ such that $m_1+2m_2+3m_3=3$, with each $m_i\geq0$. Such tuples are: $(3,0,0)$, $(1,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$. So
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d^3}{dx^3}\cos^4(x)
&=\frac{3!}{3!}f^{(3)}(\cos(x))\left(\cos^{(1)}(x)\right)^3
+\frac{3!}{2!}f^{(2)}(\cos(x))\cos^{(1)}(x)\cos^{(2)}(x)
+\frac{3!}{3!}f^{(1)}(\cos(x))\cos^{(3)}(x)\\
&=24\cos(x)\left(-\sin^3(x)\right)+3(12)\cos^2(x)\left(-\sin(x)\right)\left(-\cos(x)\right)+4\cos^3(x)\sin(x)\\
&=-24\sin^3(x)\cos(x)+40\sin(x)\cos^3(x)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reference of the powerful and interesting  formula .