# $nt$ derivative of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{A-\cos x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Assuming $A>1$, I'm triying to obtain the $nt-$derivative of $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{A-\cos x}$ at $x=0$, that is, $f^{(n}(0)$.

First,

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{A-\cos x}=\frac{1/A}{1-\frac{\cos x}{A}}=\frac{1}{A}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{A^k}\cos^k x$$
and then

$$f^{(n}(0)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{A^{k+1}}\,\left.\frac{d^n(\cos^k x)}{d\,x^n}\right|_{x=0}.$$
We have taht odd derivatives of $f(x)$ vanishes at $x=0$ and the even derivatives [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4519048/is-there-any-method-to-compute-fracdnd-xn-left-cos-k-x-right-o)

$$\left.\frac{d^{2n}(\cos^k x)}{d\,x^{2n}}\right|_{x=0}=\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^{n}(k-2j)^{2n}$$
Thus

$$\boxed{f^{(2n}(0)=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{A}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\,\frac{1}{(2\,A)^k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(k-2j)^{2n}}$$

I wonder if there is some way to simplify this last expression or another procedure to obtain a simplest formula.

Comment: What is the 1st derivative at $x=0$?

Comment: I think $f'(0)=0$

Comment: Sorry about my silly question, I was on a wrong track.

Comment: You can apply a formula from the “negative integer powers” and “function from trigonometric function sections” [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/9/) to get a slightly longer formula, but it will be a closed form/ finite sum/